# how to display images from ajax dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ajax, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I am using  bootstrap carousel, in that i want to load images dynamically after each click event.

First images is displying correctly but afterwords data is coming from server but ajax script not working.

**Html**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="listbox">
     <div class="item active" id="gallery-overlay">
       <img src="" alt="taufik">
     </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" id="pre" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>

   <a class="right carousel-control" id="nxt" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" id="nxt"></span>
     <span class="sr-only" >Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nxt').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url : 'DisplayImage',
        data : {
          opration : 'next',
          username : 'user1'
        },
        success : function(result) {
          $('#gallery-overlay').append('<li><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+result+'"/></li>');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: what does your result display if you place a console.log(result); call in your success function?

Comment: @LarryLane
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAACXBI…BnTTFTEMnL+OOcE0JSaU8Qmlb2fx1xgmqfpONUQYGj6npa/lLVrkA1QIvXwFXWd9Fc5z0X5w== net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Imaages are coming sequencially insted carousel.

Comment: try this `src="'+result+'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following since you are getting a result returned. It appears as if you were already adding data:image/jpeg;base64 in front of your base 64 code and the result was returning it as well.

```
//split the result by the , and get the actual base64 data
$('#gallery-overlay').append('<li><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'
+ result.split(",")[1] +'"/></li>');
```

Comment: Can you check and see the li element is being added to you ul list even if it is empty.  To make it easier replace  the contents of append with something else like  "HEY I HAVE BEEN APPENDED".